# Is it possible to use call/cc to implement recursion?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, callcc

I wonder if it is possible to define a recursive function without calling the function itself in its body but somehow using call/cc instead? Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can implement a Y combinator using `call/cc`, [as described here](http://www.okmij.org/ftp/Scheme/callcc-fixpoint.txt). (Many thanks to John Cowan for mentioning this neat post!) Quoting that post, here's Oleg's implementation:

> Corollary 1. Y combinator via `call/cc` -- Y combinator without an explicit self-application.
>
> ```
> (define (Y f)
>   ((lambda (u) (u (lambda (x) (lambda (n) ((f (u x)) n)))))
>    (call/cc (call/cc (lambda (x) x)))))
> ```
>
> Here, we used a fact that
>
> ```
> ((lambda (u) (u p)) (call/cc call/cc))
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> ((lambda (u) (u p)) (lambda (x) (x x)))
> ```
>
> are observationally equivalent.

Comment: Amazing, exactly what I want. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @wberry I've decided to find a way to quote that code snippet that's hopefully more "fair use"-compliant.

Answer (score 6):

Your question is a bit vague. In particular, it sounds like you want a system that models recursive calls without directly making recursive calls, using call/cc.  It turns out, though, that you can model recursive calls without making recursive calls and *also* without using call/cc. For instance:

```
#lang racket

(define (factorial f n)
  (if (= n 0) 1 (* n (f f (- n 1)))))

(factorial factorial 3)
```

That may seem like cheating, but it's the foundation of the Y combinator. Perhaps you can tighten up the set of restrictions you're thinking of?

P.S.: if this is homework, please cite me!

Comment: Well, I have already known this trick to do recursion. What I wonder is if a non-self-referring way using call/cc exists to define a recursive function, say your `factorial`. This is not a homework exercise! Thanks.

Comment: @plmday John's solution is already not self-referencing.  What more would you need from `call/cc`?

Comment: @SamTobin-Hochstadt Well, it is, `f` refers to itself, doesn't it? I wanna see how far we can go with `call/cc`, in particular, given its ability, can we employ it to simulate the usual or unusual way of defining a recursive function.

Comment: What do your mean by "refer to itself"?  Self-reference in a (self-) recursive function definition is of this form: you have a function definition whose body contains an occurrence of an identifier that's lexically bound to the enclosing function itself.  The definition of `factorial` that John provides does not have `factorial` appearing in the body, nor any identifier that's lexically bound to it.

Comment: Ah, OK, you are right. I mixed it with self-application. Thanks for clarifying it.

Comment: (After taking a look at oleg's post:) Yep, recursion without self-application: that *is* interesting. See, I knew there was an interesting question in there!

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid `call/cc` doesn't really have much to do with this.  There really are only two ways of defining a recursive function:

- Suppose your language allows recursive function definitions; i.e., a function body can refer to the enclosing function, or the body of a function `f` can refer to a function `g` whose body refers to `f`.  In this case, well, you just write it in the usual way.
- If your language forbids both of these, but it still has first-class functions and lambdas, then you can use a [fixed-point combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator) like the Y combinator.  You write your function so that it takes as an extra argument a function that's meant to represent the recursive step; every place where you would recurse, instead you invoke that argument.

So for `factorial`, you write it like this:

```
(define (factorial-step recurse n)
  (if (zero? n)
      1
      (* n (recurse (- n 1)))))
```

The magic of the Y combinator is that it constructs the `recurse` function that would be fed to `factorial-step`.